# Hyperlink cannot be clicked while jQuery script is running

Tags: jquery, html, internet-explorer, firefox

I'm using Internet Explorer 11 and Mozilla Firefox 51.0.1. Why cannot I click a hyperlink while jQuery script is running? I run the code every 5 seconds. The code will replace the HTML code of a div element. The HTML code has hundreds of rows, and this all takes several seconds. The link can be clicked before and after but not while running the script.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  get_bio_data = function() {
    var bio = 106;

    jQuery.post("get_bio.php", {
      bio: bio
    }).done(function(data) {
      $('#bio').html(data);
    });
  };

  setInterval(get_bio_data, 5000);
});
```

And here is the HTML code:

```
<div id="bio"><a href="go.html">Link 1</a>, <a href="yo.html">link 2</a>, and other HTML code, hundreds of rows...</div>
```

What to do?

Comment: I see nothing wrong with what you have given..

Comment: Yes, the code works fine. But when the function get_bio_data is running, I cannot click the link on div which ID is bio.

Comment: I can't recreate it.. got an example somewhere?

Comment: I'm using Internet Explorer 11.

Comment: What is in the response from the POST request to `get_bio.php`?

Comment: It will success. A lot of HTML code will be returned.